# CXCallObserverDelegate not being invoked

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native, callkit

Note: I am new to Objective C

I have implemented the CXCallObserverDelegate callChanged delegate in my custom React Native module but it is not invoked when i receive a VOIP call

In didFinishLaunchingWithOptions of AppDelegate

```
CallManager *manager = [CallManager new];
[manager someMethod:@"Hoola"]; // sending a test string to print
```

In CallManager.m

```
#import "CallManager.h"
#import "RNCallKeep.h"

@implementation CallManager

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE();

-(void)someMethod: (NSString *)someString
{
  
  NSLog(@"Hello world callObserver %@", someString); // Hoola string gets printed here means this method is working

  CXCallObserver *callObserver = [[CXCallObserver alloc] init];
  self.callObserver = callObserver;
  [callObserver setDelegate:(id)self queue:nil]; 

}

-(void)callObserver:(CXCallObserver *)callObserver callChanged:(CXCall *)call {
  NSLog(@"Hello world callObserver"); // this doesnt get printed when call is received or status changes
}

@end
```

In my CallManager.h file

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>
#import <CallKit/CallKit.h>


NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface CallManager : NSObject<RCTBridgeModule, CXCallObserverDelegate>

@property (atomic, strong) CXCallObserver *callObserver;
- (void)someMethod: (NSString *)someString;

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

App is compiling fine and launching and performing all things but when I receive a VOIP call and CallKIT UI is invoked, i don't get call status changed events on accept or reject. Note that NSLogs are printed correctly, i put them there for debug and they are working.

Comment: You haven't shown the first line in context, but from what you have written, your `CallManager` instance is only in a local variable. It will be discarded as soon as the method returns. You need to hold a strong reference in a property.

Comment: @Paulw11 yes you're right CallManager is a local variable in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions